# deleting duplicates

Tags: mysql

From this SO POST [Finding Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql), how can I delete duplicates.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, list.address FROM list 
INNER JOIN (SELECT address FROM list 
GROUP BY address HAVING count(id) > 1) dup ON list.address = dup.address
```

Comment: Do you mean "how can I DELETE duplicate rows from the base table" or "how can I ensure there are no duplicate rows in the output from SELECT"?  They are two significantly different problems.  The second is probably better termed 'eliminating duplicates (from a result set)' as DELETE has connotations of changing a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the DISTINCT keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT firstname FROM list;
```

if any of the output is a duplicate, mysql will remove them.

for more documentation on DISTINCT go here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-removing-eliminating-duplicates-from-a-mysql-table/

Comment: not sure why you keep editing it, not to clear on what you want tho. if your looking to remove duplicates DISTINCT will take care of that.