# mysql select ONLY duplicate records from database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do something with the duplicate records in a mysql database. however, I don't want to delete the records, and only two columns are duplicate. How can I find just these records?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 10, accepted):

can you post more information about the table structure and what do you mean that some are duplicate but only by two columns ?

Anyway, you can look into the `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, and `HAVING`

```
SELECT `duped_field1`, `duped_field2`, COUNT(*) `tot`
FROM `table`
GROUP BY `duped_field1`, `duped_field2`
HAVING `tot` > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The general principle for finding duplicates is to just use `group by` and `having count(*) > 1`

If you just want to know the duplicate column values:

```
select col1, col2
from table
group by col1, col2
having count(*) > 1
```

If however you want to see all fields where the two columns are duplicated:

```
select t.*
from @tbl t
where exists (select * 
              from @tbl d 
              where d.col1 = t.col1 and d.col2 = t.col2
              group by d.col1 
              having COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: or simply add a `*` .. `SELECT *, COUNT(*) tot`