# How to display 2 or more duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

i need to show 2 duplicate rows in a query where in

```
ID | Name | Address
--------------------
1  | John | 123 West Ave
2  | John | 123 West Ave
3  | Peter | 225 North
4  | Sally | 972 Kingsburg
5  | Peter | 225 North
6  | John |  772 Superman
7  | Peter | 882 Batman
```

and the result will be

```
ID | Name | Address
---------------------
1  | John | 123 West Ave
2  | John | 123 West Ave
3  | Peter | 225 North
5  | Peter | 225 North
```

Comment: you means want to show only those records which are duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql select ONLY duplicate records from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540996/mysql-select-only-duplicate-records-from-database)

Comment: @HamzaZafeer yes, exactly.

Comment: @Simplicity i tried that too but still no luck :(

Comment: Question is now and after answers were given; are you getting "any" output at all? If something is failing here, we don't know about it. The question's a bit short on detail.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry i just updated my post.

Comment: Tim's answer seems to solve this. Did you try it? Plus, I placed a comment under one of the answers below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes sir Tim's answer really solved my problem, thank you :)

Comment: Glad to see you got your solution and you're welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show only records whose `name` and `address` come in pair duplicates, then you can try the following query:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.name, t1.address
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name, address
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name, address
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) t2
    ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.address = t2.address
```

If you want *any* set of records which appear two or *more* times, then you can change the `HAVING` clause to `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2`.

Comment: thank you sir. it totally worked!. i've been searching for this for 4hrs now. thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

With aggregate functions?

```
SELECT ID, Name, Address
FROM le_table
GROUP BY Name, Address
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: i tried using your query command, it doesn't show 2 duplicate rows like what i illustrated above. :(

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1` given the added info, should (probably) read as `HAVING COUNT(Name) >= 2` and/or using the `Address` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY Name, Address
HAVING COUNT(ID) > 1
ORDER BY ID
```