# How to improve MySql query that trying to find duplicate entries in large database?

Tags: mysql, dataset, acid, snort

I have to make my query on large database (Snort alerts) to find duplicate entries. However, I came up with bellow query, but it takes so many time to be executed!

```
SELECT sid, cid, timestamp, sig_name, inet_ntoa(ip_src), layer4_sport,
       inet_ntoa(ip_dst), layer4_dport
  FROM DB
 WHERE (ip_dst IN
        (SELECT ip_dst FROM DB GROUP BY ip_dst HAVING count(*) > 1)
   AND timestamp IN
        (SELECT timestamp FROM DB GROUP BY timestamp HAVING count(*) > 1)
   AND layer4_dport IN
        (SELECT layer4_dport FROM DB GROUP BY layer4_dport HAVING count(*)>1 ))
```

The above query trying to find alerts ip_dst that has same  `timestamp` and `layer4_dport`
if the they came more than one time. I hope its clear!

Any tips or tricks to make it efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've formatted your query... if we break it down you seem to be applying a couple of functions `inet_ntoa`. If you don't have a pressing need for then get rid of them ( especially if they look at a table ).

Secondly, if we look at your query you are doing a full scan of `DB` 3 times for your various counts, and then at the very minimum a range scan in your top level select.

```
SELECT sid, cid, timestamp, sig_name, inet_ntoa(ip_src), layer4_sport, inet_ntoa(ip_dst), layer4_dport 
  FROM DB 
 WHERE ( ip_dst IN ( SELECT ip_dst 
                       FROM DB 
                      GROUP BY ip_dst 
                     HAVING count(*) > 1 ) 
   AND timestamp IN ( SELECT timestamp 
                        FROM DB 
                       GROUP BY timestamp 
                      HAVING count(*) > 1 ) 
   AND layer4_dport IN ( SELECT layer4_dport 
                           FROM DB 
                          GROUP BY layer4_dport 
                         HAVING count(*) > 1 ) 
        )
```

By not linking your subquery back to the main table, you've assumed that `ip_dst`, `timestamp` and `layer4_dport` are *each* unique across the whole table and then are trying to find where the unlikely occurrence of 3 independently unique values happened to have duplicates in the same row.

I suspect what you want to do is something like the following:

```
SELECT a.sid, a.cid, a.ip_dst, a.timestamp, a.sig_name, a.layer4_sport, a.layer4_dport 
  FROM DB a 
  JOIN ( SELECT timestamp, layer4_dport 
           FROM DB 
          GROUP BY timestamp, layer4_dport
         HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
    ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp
   AND a.layer4_dport = b.layer4_dport
```

This finds you all the rows where there are more than 1 identical `timestamp` and `layer4_dport` combinations as per your question.

If you want to find all the duplicates at the level of `ip_dst` then you need to add this to your sub-query.

Comment: Thank you Ben,I have added ip_dst and also I returned inet_ntoa to the query cause I want to print the result of it.But,always I got error Column'timestamp' in field list is ambiguous
and the query is like the following:
SELECT sid, cid, timestamp, sig_name, inet_ntoa(ip_src), layer4_sport, inet_ntoa(ip_dst), layer4_dport
  FROM DB a 
  JOIN ( SELECT timestamp, layer4_dport, ip_dst
           FROM DB 
          GROUP BY timestamp, layer4_dport, ip_dst
         HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
    ON a.timestamp = b.timestamp
   AND a.layer4_dport = b.layer4_dport
   AND a.ip_dst = b.ip_dst
-Aymen

Comment: Working fine now. I just added a.timestamp on the select sentence as following:
SELECT sid, cid, a.timestamp, sig_name, inet_ntoa(ip_src), layer4_sport, inet_ntoa(a.ip_dst), a.layer4_dport
  FROM DB a ....

Thanks a lot Ben,

-Aymen

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry @user1247874, I didn't explicitly reference which table the select variables came from. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The link below could help you.

[Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

I hope that this post can help you optimize your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My query is similar  less or more to the ideas that have been posted on the post. The query is working fine, but I am looking for a better way to make it efficient.

Comment: @user1247874: Not actually. As you can see from the post above given by Ben, your query is far from the ideas presented in the link that I gave you. Check the answer given above and then the one given in the link by Powerlord. You should be getting closer to what you need by following these.

Comment: Thanks. your interesting is highly appreciated.

Aymen