# Check against multiple duplicate records

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

Before inserting data into table i need to check against duplicate records and report list of those records. 
Query should not insert anything while there is at least one duplicate.

Number of records to insert: ~1000

Rows in table: ~1.000.000

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `A` varchar(19) NOT NULL,
  `B` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  KEY `A` (`A`),
  KEY `B` (`B`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to check for both columns:

What is the efficient way of doing this.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. consider using php and mysql

Comment: Actually nothing. The only thing that comes to mind is to check every single record against duplication. But it doesn't seem efficient.
What would you do?

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using a unique key to reject duplicates?

Comment: @Turgut: we aren't fond of people who try nothing before asking a question :) You should go and try *something*. Maybe you'll have a better question. Maybe you'll have no question at all.

Comment: I need to get list of duplicate records before insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say duplicate means a username already exists. so you can try:

1] use a for loop to group all usernames that's in your insert list: pseudo code follows:

```
  $names="";
  for(each element){
      $names.=$val.", ";
  //remove last comma ","
```

Then use following sql statement to get all duplicate entries.

```
  select * from myTable where username in ($names);
```

having obtained a list of all your duplicates, then insert as

```
insert into myTable (username, address, otherstuff)
values("henry", "35 skid", "who knows")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
otherstuff = values(otherstuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it might be to insert everything anyway, then [select duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) in order to output them; and if any are found to rollback the entire operation. That would be quite expensive though.