# MYSQL to display only the earliest of duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
select name, reported_at from nodes
where reported_at < curdate() or reported_at is null
group by name
```

Output:

```
name                reported at
ncs-linux-test.edu  2012-03-16 18:36:03
ocdev1.net          2012-04-06 16:32:02
pinc-ctm.net        NULL
```

With that statement, I get any results form reported at/name that are less than the current date.

What I need though is the statement to only pull out data that has a duplicate(s) with more current information.

For example:

The statement would only pull out:

```
ncs-linux-test.edu    2012-03-16
```

if there was an

```
ncs-linux-test.edu
```

with a date more current than 2012-03-16.

Comment: That's essentially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql, and then you pick the earliest per group.

Comment: What are you expecting to get if you have duplicates both with null values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from nodes n 
join nodes nlater
  on n.name = nlater.name 
  and n.reportedat < nlater.reportedat
```