# Returning a count of duplicate rows based on 3 matching column entries

Tags: sql

In a table, I want to return duplicate rows based on three columns and a count of the duplicates found.

For example,
In a row, say I have an entry of 1 for column a, 1 for column b and 1 for column c.
I only want to return/count this row if other rows have the exact same entry for the 3 columns (1, 1 and 1).

Thanks in advance!
-N

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

```
-- You need to specify the columns you need, and the count
SELECT   col1, col2, col3, COUNT(*)
FROM     myTable
-- Then you have to group the tuples based on the columns you are doing the count on
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
-- Here you specify the condition for COUNT(*)
HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1;
```

You can find more information about this [here](http://database-programmer.blogspot.ca/2008/04/group-by-having-sum-avg-and-count.html) (plus some other useful stuff).