# MySQL List All Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

I have a table in MySQL like this:

```
ID    name    email
1    john     abc@abc.com
2    johnny   abc@abc.com
3    jim      eee@eee.com
4    Michael  abec@awwbc.com
```

How can I have the MySQL query that will list out the duplicate one like this?

Result of duplicate search:

```
ID    name    email         Duplicate
1    john     abc@abc.com      2
2    johnny   abc@abc.com      2
```

Comment: This exact question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalCount AS Duplicate
FROM    tablename a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  email, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY email
        ) b ON a.email = b.email
WHERE   b.totalCount >= 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dc584/1)

for better performance, add an `INDEX` on column `EMail`.

OR

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalCount AS Duplicate
FROM    tablename a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  email, COUNT(*) totalCount
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP   BY email
            HAVING  COUNT(*) >= 2
        ) b ON a.email = b.email
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5dc584/2)

Comment: @JW im doing something wrong, or you wrote too complicated query? See my answer.

Comment: @Kamil the result of your query must have two records: `ID 1 and 2`.

Comment: I guess you miss-understanding what I am asking here. There is only one table and the table below is the result from the mySQL query, not another table in the database.

Comment: @user1995781 the query involves only one table.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with having the ID and name in comma separated lists, then you can try:

```
select email, count(*) as numdups,
       group_concat(id order by id), group_concat(name order by id)
from t
group by email
having count(*) > 1
```

This saves a join, although the result is not in a relational format.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,180556,180572#msg-180572) on the [MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com), which gives the following:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t1.email FROM t1 INNER JOIN ( 
SELECT colA,colB,COUNT(*) FROM t1 GROUP BY colA,colB HAVING COUNT(*)>1) as t2 
ON t1.email = t2.email;
```