# How do I locate duplicate records before I create a UNIQUE key?

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint

I'm going to create a UNIQUE key in a large, old table (several hundred thousand rows) to enforce each row containing unique data. I can't just up and create the index though, because the table already contains some duplicates. I don't know how many duplicates it contains, or if the duplicates are necessary. In short, I can't analyse the problem before I can come up with a query that selects all the rows that would violate the future UNIQUE key.

Say I have a table with the fields **col_one**, **col_two**, **col_three** and **col_four**. My future UNIQUE key will contain **col_two** and **col_three**. How do I select all the rows in the table where **col_two** and **col_three** has a duplicate in the same table?

Comment: You can scroll through this to find duplicate records in a column.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Use a group.

```
SELECT 
  col_two,
  col_three,
  COUNT (*) AS `num_dupes`
FROM
  your_table
GROUP BY
  col_two,
  col_three
HAVING 
  COUNT(*) > 1 -- Only return results where there is at least one duplicate.
```

If you want to see all results from your table where duplicates exist, you can just join from these results to the table:

```
SELECT
  your_table.*
FROM
  your_table
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
      col_two,
      col_three,
      COUNT (*) AS `num_dupes`
    FROM
      your_table
    GROUP BY
      col_two,
      col_three
    HAVING 
      COUNT(*) > 1) dupes 
      ON your_table.col_two = dupes.col_two AND
         your_table.col_three = dupes.col_three
```

Comment: Would it be possible to select all the duplicate rows without grouping them? In case I want to examine the difference in columns that aren't included in the UNIQUE key. Perhaps I would need to include a programming language at this point.

Comment: You can quite easily do this by chaining on another query based on the results of this query. I'll add that to my answer.