# How I create a table without singles records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

For example, I have the next table (IN MySQL)

```
| a | 1002 |
| b | 1002 |
| c | 1015 |
| a | 1005 |
| b | 1016 |
| a | 1106 |
| d | 1006 |
| a | 1026 |
| f | 1106 |
```

I want to select the objects that are duplicates.

```
| a | 1002 |
| a | 1106 |    
| a | 1026 | 
| a | 1005 |
| b | 1002 |   
| b | 1016 |
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate, already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you want to select rows where the number column is duplicated. One way to do it is to join against a subquery returns a list of `number` values that occur more than once.

```
SELECT letter, number
FROM myTable A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT number
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY number
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) B ON A.number = B.number
```

Comment: Your query won't return the results a user is expecting. You should do grouping and joining on a letter rather than on a number.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, if you want the list of all values where there are duplicates, you can use `group_concat`:

```
select col1, group_concat(col2)
from t
group by col1
having count(*) > 1
```

This does *not* return the exact format you want.  Instead it would return:

```
| a | 1002,1106,1026,1005 |
| b | 1002,1016 |
```

But you might find it useful.