# MySQL Locate Duplicates between two table with similar column

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql).  I'm trying to find duplicate records between two tables by the column names `matrix_unique_id` and `Matrix_Unique_ID` in each table and then display the full address.  The Full address columns are formatted differently from each other in each table so I cannot use that as a comparison.  I'm getting an "unknown column fort_property_res.matrix_unique_id" error but everything looks okay?

So two questions:

1. Will this query find duplicates correctly?
2. Why the unknown column error?

SQL query:

```
SELECT matrix_unique_id, full_address 
FROM fort_property_res
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Matrix_Unique_ID, FullAddress 
    FROM sunshinemls_property_res
    GROUP BY FullAddress 
    HAVING count(fort_property_res.matrix_unique_id) > 1
) dup ON fort_property_res.matrix_unique = sunshinemls_property_res.Matrix_Unique_ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you're trying to copy is a totally different case. You have two tables and (it looks like) a convenient matrix_unique_id to join on, so this is much easier:

```
SELECT fort.matrix_unique_id, fort.full_address AS fortAddress, sun.FullAddress AS sunAddress
FROM fort_property_res fort, sunshinemls_property_res sun
WHERE fort.matrix_unique_id = sun.Matrix_Unique_ID
```