# Get Duplicates efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, database, duplicates

I'm really stuck at the moment, as my query works, but only with some sample data, in the actual database with 15'000 clients I don't even get a response in time.

I have the following table:

```
-Client-
id
firstname
lastname
```

Now my query has to get all possible duplicates and list them, so lets say we have Client A with id 1, B with id 2 and C with id = 3 that have the same first- and lastname. The output should look like this:

```
id | duplicateID | client | duplicate
1  | 2           | A      | B
1  | 3           | A      | C
2  | 3           | B      | C
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS clientID,
  d.id AS duplicateID,
  CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullName
FROM Client AS c
JOIN Client AS d
  ON d.lastname = c.lastname
  AND d.firstname = c.firstname
  AND d.id != c.id
  AND d.id > c.id
ORDER BY fullName, c.id
```

Is there any way to increase the performance **without losing any results?** I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) answer, but there I only get one duplicate per client, where I want all of the duplicates.

Any help or tip is appreciated, thanks

Edit: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02dda3/4) as requested

Comment: can u give sqlfiddle example ? and wished result ?

Comment: Please provide proper DDLs

Comment: from that fiddle you gave , what result you want get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query every so slightly simplified (one `on` condition is removed).

```
SELECT c.id AS clientID, d.id AS duplicateID, CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullName
FROM Client c JOIN
     Client d
     ON d.lastname = c.lastname AND d.firstname = c.firstname AND d.id > c.id
ORDER BY fullName, c.id;
```

Try using an index.

```
create index client_lastname_firstname_id on client(lastname, firstname, id);
```

This should facilitate the `join`.  If you have a lot of data, the `order by` could become a performance bottleneck.

Another solution would be to put all the duplicates on one line.  This only involves a `group by`, and gives the list of duplicate ids for each name:

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) AS fullName,
       group_concat(c.id order by c.id) AS clientIDs
 FROM Client c 
GROUP BY c.firstname, c.lastname;
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Only adding the index reduced the runtime from 58 seconds to 0.09 seconds!

Comment: @MichaelKunst . . . Wow!  A 99.8% improvement.  That's pretty good ;)