# Find duplicate records based on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I'm trying to modify the accepted answer in this question: [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) in order to find duplicate records in my table based on two fields, Firstname and Lastname.

This is the original query which works fine and finds duplicate records based on Lastname...

```
SELECT Firstname, candidate.Lastname FROM candidate
INNER JOIN (SELECT Lastname FROM candidate
GROUP BY Lastname HAVING count(UserID) > 1) dup ON 
candidate.Lastname = dup.Lastname ORDER BY Lastname
```

Now I want to add Firstname in there as well... but I'm not really sure what I'm doing, the following doesn't work:

```
SELECT candidate.Firstname, candidate.Lastname FROM candidate
INNER JOIN (SELECT Firstname AND Lastname FROM candidate
GROUP BY Lastname HAVING count(UserID) > 1) dup ON 
candidate.Lastname = dup.Lastname AND candidate.Firstname = dup.Firstname 
ORDER BY Lastname
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just got the syntax a bit wrong in the sub-query, maybe this is what you want?

```
SELECT candidate.Firstname, candidate.Lastname 
FROM candidate
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Firstname, Lastname 
    FROM candidate
    GROUP BY Firstname, Lastname 
    HAVING COUNT(UserID) > 1
    ) dup 
    ON candidate.Lastname = dup.Lastname AND candidate.Firstname = dup.Firstname
ORDER BY Lastname
```