# Remove duplicate records from a query created in the same day

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am trying to create a SQL query that pulls all unique records created in the same day. Example:

```
Table 1
Field 1     Field 2         Field 3
Bob         bob@yahoo.com   2015-07-15
Rob         rob@gmail.com   2015-07-16
Tiffany     bob@yahoo.com   2015-07-15
```

the result should be:

```
Field 1     Field 2         Field 3
Bob         bob@yahoo.com   2015-07-15
Rob         rob@gmail.com   2015-07-16
```

I tried to use select distinct, but I need the result to contain all fields. De-duplication should be on email address and it can pull either the first or last entry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Although not guaranteed to work, the following probably will do what you want:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
group by field2, field3;
```

MySQL does not guarantee that the fields come from the same row.  In fact, the documentation is quite clear that the columns come from *indeterminate* (but matching) rows.  In practice, the values do seem to come from the same row.

If you want more control, you can use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@e = email, @rn + 1,
                        if(@e := email, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from table1 t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @e := '') param
      order by email
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! it really helps to have this level of detail for other queries that I have yet to get to.

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from table1
group by Field3
```

Comment: This doesn't do deduplication based on email address (field2) as required by the OP.

Comment: of course, so simple! thank you, I will try that approach!