# How can I delete duplicated rows based on more column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have got a database with movies and it's links.
One movie may has more links.
Unfortunately some of them has the same link twice.

For example:

```
row1 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink1
row2 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink1
row3 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink2
row4 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink3
row5 Minions http://www.minionslink1
row6 Minions http://www.minionslink1
```

I would like to delete that rows which are more than one in the table, but keep one of them.
So I would like this:

```
row1 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink1
row3 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink2
row4 Alien vs. Predator http://www.avplink3
row5 Minions http://www.minionslink1
```

How can I write an SQL query which delete these rows?
Thanks!

EDIT:

I solved with this code:

```
DELETE a            
FROM links a            
JOIN (SELECT MIN(id) id, movielink
FROM links 
GROUP BY movielink) b ON a.movielink= b.movielink 
AND a.id <> b.id
```

Thanks everyone the help!

Comment: Do you have a unique id in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) except put

```
delete from
```

instead of

```
select * from
```

Comment: Yes, with this: SELECT * FROM links
INNER JOIN (SELECT movielink FROM links
GROUP BY movielink HAVING count(id) > 1) mov ON links.movielink = mov.movielink   - I can list out the duplicated movie links but if I change the select * to delete, I got this error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN (SELECT movielink FROM links
GROUP BY movielink HAVING count(id) > 1)' at line 2

Answer (score 1):

This is a pain without a unique id in each row (all tables should have a primary key).  Probably the easiest way is to use a temporary table in that case:

```
create temporary table tempt as
    select distinct movie, link
    from t;

truncate table t;

insert into t(movie, link)
    select movie, link
    from tempt;
```

There are simpler ways if you have a unique id.  After doing this, put a unique index on the table to prevent this from happening in the future:

```
create unique index idx_t_movie_link on t(movie, link);
```

Actually, I think this statement will also delete duplicate rows, but I don't recommend using index creation to delete rows.

EDIT:

If you have a unique row identifier, then you can just do:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select movie, link, min(rowid) as minrowid
          from t
          group by movie, link
         ) tt
         on t.movie = tt.movie and t.link = tt.link and t.rowid <> tt.minrowid
```