# Reduce mysql database to elminiate duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "lane" with the following properties.

```
CREATE TABLE `lane` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `origRegion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `origState` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `destRegion` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `destState` char(2) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

There are duplicate rows in this table of the following columns: origState, origRegion, destState, destRegion. I'd like to be able to select all rows JOINED to what the min(id) is of the first occurance.

For example, with data:

```
1 ALL MA ALL OH
2 ALL MA ALL OH
3 ALL MA ALL OH
```

and a SQL similar to this (which misses all the duplicate rows):

```
select l.*, l2.count, l2.minId from tmpLane l 
JOIN (SELECT id, min(ID) as minId from tmpLane 
  GROUP BY origRegion, origState, destRegion, destState) l2 on l.id = l2.id;
```

Result (note the count and minId at the end):

```
1 ALL MA ALL OH 3 1
2 ALL MA ALL OH 3 1
3 ALL MA ALL OH 3 1
```

Note, that the query used above is an adaptation of the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) (which doesn't work in this situation)

Comment: Is the last result you show what you want to get or is it the wrong result? Please show what is the expected result

Comment: Would a query that deletes all dups work better for you?

Comment: The result shown is what I expect. What I'm actually getting is just 1 row. A delete query won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, 
       origRegion, 
       origState, 
       destRegion, 
       destState,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Lane l3
        WHERE l.origRegion = l3.origRegion
        and l.origState = l3.origState
        and l.destRegion = l3.destRegion
        and l.destState = l3.destState) as 'Count', 
       (SELEcT MIN(ID) 
        FROM Lane l2 
        WHERE l.origRegion = l2.origRegion
        and l.origState = l2.origState
        and l.destRegion = l2.destRegion
        and l.destState = l2.destState) as minID
FROM lane l
```

Comment: I don't JUST want the first occurrence, I want all occurences with the added column providing a single unique instance (min(id)).

Answer (score 1):

You can run this query to remove all the duplicate rows from your database:-

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `lane`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`origRegion`, `origState`, `destRegion`, `destState`);
```

This will add unique index to your table and remove all dulicate rows and will make sure that no duplicate rows being inserted in future.

Comment: The issue is that the OP wants the COUNT of the duplicate rows displayed for each row, not just to remove or ignore them completely.

Comment: The count is helpful just to see how many there are. I do not want to delete the rows. I only want to select which have duplicates and propose a single instance (min) that could be used.