# Find duplicate data in table using mysql

Tags: mysql

This my table structure :

```
id    emp_id    log_date
1        1      2015-1-1
2        1      2015-1-1
3        1      2015-1-2
4        2      2015-1-1
5        2      2015-1-2
6        2      2015-1-2
```

I want to pull duplicate `log_date` for every `emp_id` seperately.

Expected output:

```
id    emp_id    log_date
1        1      2015-1-1
2        1      2015-1-1
5        2      2015-1-2
6        2      2015-1-2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find duplicate records by many ways.
Some of are as below:
1.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` GROUP BY emp_id, log_date having count(emp_id) > 1;
```

By the below query you can fetch the exact times the record is repeating.

```
SELECT emp_id, count(*) as cnt FROM `table_name` GROUP BY log_date having cnt > 1 ORDER BY cnt desc=;
```

Second way is to use the auto increment Id that is 'id'. It is always unique so we can use to it to find duplicate records.

```
SELECT n1.* FROM table_name n1, table_name n2 WHERE n1.`id` < n2.`id` AND n1.emp_id = n2.emp_id AND n1.log_date = n2.log_date
```

Hope this will work. Please Mark the anset as accepted if you are satisfied. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned  query for required result :

```
select id,emp_id,log_data from table group by emp_id,log_data;
```

If you want only duplicate data then use:

```
select id,emp_id,log_data from table group by emp_id,log_data having count(1)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
inner join (
    select emp_id, log_date from yourtable group by emp_id, log_date having count(*) > 1
) t2 on t2.emp_id = t1.emp_id and t2.log_date = t1.log_date
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b077a/2)

Comment: There could be more optimized way, Please try this :

SELECT n1.* FROM table_name n1, table_name n2 WHERE n1.`id` < n2.`id` AND n1.emp_id = n2.emp_id AND n1.log_date = n2.log_date

Comment: You can refer to the link below, it have many and very optimized solutions:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051373/find-duplicate-data-in-table-using-mysql

Comment: @AmanGarg Wow, what do you want me to do? Accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cross join` as follows. The query is simply checking if the data matches but the `id` doesn't.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM
tablename t1, tablename t2
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id 
AND t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
AND t1.log_date = t2.log_date
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it with **HAVING** like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt, t.*
FROM yourtable t
group by emp_id,log_date
having cnt >1;
```