# How to find and remove duplicate records from multiple column,keep only one full record

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, mysql-workbench

I am trying to find duplicates from a table based on multiple columns. I have a table which has a columns like Email(Office),Email(Personal1) & Email_Personal2, Mobile_Personal1, Mobile_Personal2, FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,CompanyName,Designation etc. It has millions of records. There are so many duplicates for a specific record.

The folowing image represents the sample Table:
[image]

Now, I want to find the record using sql query which has the full values in its columns, want to keep this record and delete remaining all.

```
select *,count(*) from mytable where first_name!="" group by First_Name,Email_Office,Email_Personal1,Email_Personal2,Personal_Mobile1,Personal_Mobile2 having count(*)>1
```

But its showing me a specific record with total number of occurrence in last count(*) column only. Guide me in above query how can I see a record which has all the details along with number of occurrences of that specific record? How do I keep that one complete record and delete remaining all from a table?

I've removed "having count(*) >1" to see each record from above query but its taking so much time to show the output,almost feel like its getting hanged.

```
select t.*  from mytable t inner join  (select first_name,middle_name,last_name,designation,company_name,email_office,email_personal1,email_personal2,personal_mobile1,personal_mobile2,count(*) as NoDuplicates   from mytable   group by first_name,middle_name,last_name,designation,company_name,email_office,email_personal1,email_personal2,personal_mobile1,personal_mobile2  having NoDuplicates > 1) tsum on t.first_name=tsum.first_name and t.Middle_Name=tsum.middle_name and t.Last_Name=tsum.last_name and t.Designation=tsum.designation and t.Company_Name=tsum.company_name and t.Email_Office=tsum.email_office and t.Email_Personal1=tsum.email_personal1 and t.Email_Personal2=tsum.email_personal2 and t.Personal_Mobile1=tsum.personal_mobile1 and t.Personal_Mobile2=tsum.personal_mobile2
```

Comment: Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Does your table have an ID column? What is the PK?

Comment: Yes it has. SrNo which has PK.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql ?

Comment: Yes I did.I am not getting why its taking these much time to execute.. I am going to paste it in my question. If you or anyone can help me whats wrong in it.