# What is the query in MySQL to pull out the duplicate records

Tags: mysql, duplicates

Want to find duplicate records in a MySQL Database. This could be written with:

```
SELECT address, count(id) as cnt FROM list
GROUP BY address HAVING cnt > 1
```

Which gives me:

```
101 Saint ST    3
```

I want to pull it so that it shows each row that is duplicate. example like:

```
SIM    JANE    101 Saint ST
JOHN   SMITH   101 Saint ST
```

Anyone have any idea how it could be done? I'm trying to avoid doing the first one then looking up the duplicates with a second query in the code.

Comment: It's already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Comment: @Mac23 How.. can it be the same exact question?? Are you a bot or something?

Answer (score 0):

One option here is to join your original table to a subquery which determines the counts:

```
SELECT t1.last, t1.first, t1.address
FROM list t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT address
    FROM list
    GROUP BY address
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.address = t2.address
```

The subquery servers a filter which removes records not having at least one other record with a common address.  Note that I removed the `COUNT` from the select list of this subquery, since you don't appear to be using it in your final result.