# Compare one row of resultset with remaining all and find duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to find duplicate rows from my resultset. I have a large data in resultset, which is the best way to find duplicates from resultset? I've tried with arraylist too.

```
List inner=new ArrayList<String>();
Connection con;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
ResultSetMetaData rsmd;
int columnNumber;

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb","root","");
    stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from mydata_table where srno<1000");
    rsmd=rs.getMetaData();
    columnNumber=rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()){

        for(int i=1;i<columnNumber;i++){
            inner.add(rs.getString(i));
        }

   }           
   System.out.println("\n" + inner);

   rs.close();
   con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I want to compare one row with remaining rows and find duplicate rows from the list.

Comment: Then why don't you use `DISTINCT` clause in SQL? That would be cleaner solution

Comment: This sounds like something that should be done with SQL rather than the `ResultSet`.

Comment: I've tried DISTINCT clause but it didn't return unique records in my case.

Comment: What is `inner` here?

Comment: You can do that all in SQL see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql for a get you started answer

Comment: Instead of `ArrayList` you can use `Set` that would solve(at-least with code you have pasted)

Comment: @Simze you mean I need to store resultset in a set?

Comment: Yes if you're using only one column from resultset like in your code.

Comment: No there are more than 40 columns in my resultset. I am bit confused, how to solve it..What is the best approach to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you sort the records in the query (probably `ORDER BY ...`) you then only need to compare each record with it's successor.

Comment: Thank you for your help.But there are more than 40 columns in it, order by with which column?

Comment: @iks_in - All of them if you like. Or as many of them that will make the duplicate check easy. If, for example, columns 1,2 and 3 are generally unique in most records, sort by them and then only search forward while all of them are the same.