# Getting multiple distinct data in each column from different tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all distinct columns(`projectName`, `villageName`, `blockName`, `lotName` from 5 different tables(`tbl_project`,`tbl_village`,`tbl_block`,`tbl_lot`).

When I try to use this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT`projectName`, `villageName`, `blockName`, `lotName`
                  FROM `tbl_property`
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_project` ON tbl_property.projectID = tbl_project.projectID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_village` ON tbl_property.villageID = tbl_village.villageID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_block`   ON tbl_property.blockID   = tbl_block.blockID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_lot`     ON tbl_property.lotID     = tbl_lot.lotID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_model`   ON tbl_property.model     = tbl_model.modelID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_street`  ON tbl_property.street    = tbl_street.streetID
                  WHERE tbl_property.propertyStatus =  1  
                  GROUP BY `projectName`, `villageName`, `blockName`, lotName
                  ORDER BY `projectName` ASC, `villageName` ASC, `blockName` ASC, `lotName` ASC
```

I get the distinct `projectName` and `villageName` but when I add `blockName`:
`SELECT DISTINCT`projectName`,`villageName`,`blockName`...` It doesn't go distinct. This goes same with `lotName`. But it shows results but there is no distinction at all.

tbl_project

```
**projectName**
Project 1
Project 1
Project 2
Project 3
```

tbl_village

```
**villageName**
Village 1
Village 2 
Village 2
Village 4
```

tbl_block

```
**blockName**
Block 1
Block 2
Block 6
Block 6
```

tbl_lot

```
**lotName**
Lot 1
Lot 2 
Lot 3
```

Expected Output:

**Project Name**----  **Village Name**----**Block Name**----**Lot Name**

Project 1    ----------      Village 1-----------Block 1-------------Lot 1

Project 2     ----------     Village 2-----------Block 2-------------Lot 2

Project 3     ----------     Village 4-----------Block 6-------------Lot 3

Comment: please add the sample data (or create SQLFIDDLE ) and desired output will be helpfull

Comment: @Noman There. Added some sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding 'blockName' to select list without purposefully leaving 'lotName' in GROUP BY clause, then it could be your problem. You can group by items not in your select list which will then display duplicates.

tldr, select items must match group by items AND remove unneeded joins.

For MYSQL see Also

[Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql#854177)

Comment: Then the issue is with your joins. Comment out the bottom two joins to see if it returns distinct values now.                  -- LEFT JOIN `tbl_model`   ON tbl_property.model     = tbl_model.modelID
                 -- LEFT JOIN `tbl_street`  ON tbl_property.street    = tbl_street.streetID

Comment: Still doesn't not return distinct values

Comment: Does this return duplicates? SELECT DISTINCT`projectName`, `villageName`, `blockName`, `lotName`
                  FROM `tbl_property`
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_project` ON tbl_property.projectID = tbl_project.projectID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_village` ON tbl_property.villageID = tbl_village.villageID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_block`   ON tbl_property.blockID   = tbl_block.blockID
                  LEFT JOIN `tbl_lot`     ON tbl_property.lotID     = tbl_lot.lotID

                  WHERE tbl_property.propertyStatus =  1

Comment: Yes. Its still returning duplicates

Comment: Try using a row_Number over(Partition by..) IF you are using MsSQL or Oracle. I'll post a rough example below.

Comment: If MYSQL see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql#854177

Comment: Dylan, Have you found a solution yet?  I may have misunderstood your question. I assumed Row Duplicates. Column duplicates may be another solution such as Select Distinct value1 from table t join on table2 t2 t.ID = t2.ID Where condition UNION Select Distinct value2 from table t join on table2 t2 t.ID = t2.ID Where condition