# Remove Duplicate Values From Select Option In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

here's the code and i want to echo only 1 city from mysql database!

```
<?php


include('db.php');

    $queryss = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM areas');

    while ($rowx = mysqli_fetch_array($queryss)) {


        echo "{pro:'$rowx[1]',city:'$rowx[2]', dist:'$rowx[3]', town:'$rowx[4]', area:'$rowx[5]',subarea:'$rowx[6]',ucname:'$rowx[7]'},";

    }

    ?>
```

and i'm, getting this input here! 3 time karachi in my html, but i want only 1 of this city. SELECT DISTINCT is working in mysql but how can i use it in PHP?

[image]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: can you give me the solution?

Comment: you mean `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Comment: i've entered duplicate values in mysql, now i want that when i fetch them then i'll get only 1 value, rest of the duplicate values should be deleted

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql

Comment: any code solution?

Comment: you didn't put any effort to write a clear question, I don't know why we should provide you a clear answer. We don't know what you want to do.

Comment: your answer is right bro! SELECT DISTINCT is clearly working in mysql but when i'm putting it in PHP it's giving and error of offset

Comment: ok i'm writing my question again :)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? I cannot see how the PHP code you've shared could lead to the markup from the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM areas GROUP BY id
```

I have tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`SELECT DISTINCT column_name1,column_name2 FRAM areas`

in your SQL where column_nameN stands for the columns you need for your output.

OR use something like this (untested):

```
$results = [];
while ($rowx = mysqli_fetch_array($queryss)) {
    $results[] = $rowx;
}
$results= array_unique($results);
foreach($results as $rowx) {
    echo "{pro:'$rowx[1]',city:'$rowx[2]', dist:'$rowx[3]', town:'$rowx[4]', area:'$rowx[5]',subarea:'$rowx[6]',ucname:'$rowx[7]'},";
}
```

Comment: I forgot a $. Please be more specific and try to debug yourself before asking for more help

Answer (score 0):

### First Solution

You can insert [distinct keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) into your SQL to accomplish what you need, like so

```
SELECT DISTINCT your_column_name FROM table_name
```

### Second Soltion

You can execute your SQL statement and then use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), to be like so

```
$selectStatement = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM areas');

$selectedArrayValues = mysqli_fetch_array($selectStatement);

$selectedUniqueArrayValues = array_unique(selectedArrayValues);

// Then return that array to your HTML code
```

I recommend the first solution because it's more optimized