# Find Duplicate rows & DISPLAY

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find & display duplicate rows in my mysql table.
I found a solution to FIND duplicate records, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql) article.
But Now I want to DISPLAY the found rows(Both records - Original record & Duplicates) like below.

```
    Orginal
ID   firstname  lastname ect..
100  John       Martin   blah

    Possible Duplicate/s
ID   firstname  lastname ect..
101  John       Martine   blah
```

Please help me with this. 
I have know idea how to display/print both records.

**SQL Query**

```
    SELECT firstname, 
   lastname, 
   list.address 
FROM list
   INNER JOIN (SELECT address
               FROM   list
               GROUP  BY address
               HAVING COUNT(id) > 1) dup
           ON list.address = dup.address;
```

Edit : Dear All, I am clear with mysql query. 
 I want to print is to a specific page using PHP

Answer (score 1):

Please find this query for your purpose.

```
SELECT
    l.firstname, l.lastname, COUNT(*)
FROM
    list l
GROUP BY
    l.firstname, l.lastname
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This will return duplicate records with occurrence in last column. You can alter having condition to match with your purpose. For your case, COUNT(*) > 0

Comment: I am ok with sql query. But still i haven't any idea about how to print returned records.

Comment: Can you tell me where you want to print records?

Comment: I want to print it on a page called duplicate-finder.php

Answer (score 0):

Do something along this line:

```
Select a.*, b.* from list as a, list as b where a.address=b.address and a.id<>b.id
```