# Only display duplicate records in database

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am trying to create a query to find any duplicates values and then just display those records. 
But my query is returning rows that don't contain any duplicates.

```
                SELECT j.*,             
                count(alldok.DocketNo)  AS ConsignmentCount,
                alldok.DocketNo  AS Dockets
                FROM job_new j                      
                LEFT JOIN job_dockets alldok ON alldok.JobID = j.ID
                WHERE j.IsActive = 1 
                GROUP BY j.ID  
                HAVING  ConsignmentCount > 1  
                ORDER BY  ID  DESC
```

A few of the rows that get returned:

[image]

We can see it found `CAROL EMAIL` twice but those other values are not duplicates but the count is saying 2, even though they only exist once.

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/854177/8150502

Answer (score 2):

This will return you all your duplicate docketNo

```
SELECT DocketNo FROM job_dockets group by DocketNo having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: But my query is coming from the `job_new` table then left joining to `job_dockets`. So how to do I count the `DocketNo` field?

Comment: can you create sample date so it will be more clear to query out -
 http://sqlfiddle.com/