# Filter Results in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table

```
  id            value
------        ---------
  10              123
  10              422
  11              441
  11              986
  12              674
  13              648
```

I need a query which will return only those id's which have 2 or more values associated with them. So, in that case it will only return ID 10 & 11, but i need al the records.

so the result looks like:

```
 id            value
------        ---------
  10              123
  10              422
  11              441
  11              986
```

Thank you.

Comment: Write a subquery that gets the count of rows for each ID, using `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`. Then join that with the table and filter it to `count >= 2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

```
select a2.*
from MyTable a2
inner join
(
select a1.id
from MyTable a1
group by a1.id
having count(*) > 1
) a3
on a3.id = a2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a UNIQUE KEY can be formed on (id,value)...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
           FROM my_table x
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.id = x.id
            AND y.value <> x.value
```

If a UNIQUE KEY cannot be formed on (id,value), then this isn't really a table in a strict RDBMS sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
SELECT * from table where id in 
( SELECT id FROM table group by id having count(id) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

With mysql 8+ or mariadb 10.2+, you would use the count window function:

```
select id, value
from (
    select id, value, count(id) over (partition by id) as num_values
    from sometable
) foo
where num_values > 1;
```