# How to write a query on data explore to show data like this form?

Tags: mysql

How to write a query on data explore to show output(starkoverflow question titles main) like this form:

"id","qid1","qid2","question1","question2","is_duplicate"

"0","1","2","What is the step by step guide to invest in share market in india?","What is the step by step guide to invest in share market?","0"

"1","3","4","What is the story of Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) Diamond?","What would happen if the Indian government stole the Kohinoor (Koh-i-Noor) diamond back?","0"

"2","5","6","How can I increase the speed of my internet connection while using a VPN?","How can Internet speed be increased by hacking through DNS?","0"

("id" is just a row number, this all content are just one example what we can see from a output.csv file)

Comment: This looks like `GROUP_CONCAT` _might_ be what you are looking for.  Please add some sample table data to your question, and then show us the output you expect from the query.

Comment: Where does the value for the first "id" column come from? Other than that is looks like a normal JOIN query, but maybe you are looking for something like on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql