# List of duplicates SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
ID
Link
price
```

There are some duplicates in column Link, how can I get a list of duplicates.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl
WHERE Link
IN
(SELECT Link
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Link
HAVING CONT(*) > 1;
```

It returns all the fields with duplicates, but I need to list them, so I can see all of them (fields with duplicates).

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: BTW, a table has _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Comment: What your query not gives you? you need one another column with count of duplicates? or what ?

Comment: it returns just a row with duplicates but i need to get all duplicates like: ID1 LINK1 PRISE1; ID2 LINK1 PRISE2; ID3 LINK3 PRISE3; ID4 LINK3 PRISE4;

Comment: I guess you just need to order your data by Link. just add `order by Link` to end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT Link
    FROM tbl
GROUP BY Link
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: The sub-query alone will produce the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
SELECT Link, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Link
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

In MySQL, you can even leave out the `COUNT(*)` from the SELECT.

```
SELECT Link
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Link
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Comment: it returns just a row with duplicates but i need to get all duplicates like :
ID1    LINK1    PRISE1
ID2    LINK1    PRISE2
ID3    LINK3    PRISE3
ID4    LINK3    PRISE4

Comment: In that case the query in your question shout produce the result you want (you are just missing the closing parentheses). What is wrong with the output of your original query?

Comment: It returns a result like: ID1 LINK1 PRISE1;  ID3 LINK3 PRISE3; But not all list.

Comment: And what would the "all list" look like?

Comment: ID1 LINK1 PRISE1; ID2 LINK1 PRISE2; ID3 LINK3 PRISE3; ID4 LINK3 PRISE4;

Comment: Your query will list all rows which have Link-column values that appear more than once in the data (="all list"). Please provide sample data, your query and the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full rows, then I would recommend:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where exists (select 1
              from tbl t2
              where t2.link = t.link and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

This assumes that `id` is unique, which seems like a reasonable assumption.