# Finding duplicate messages between different pairs of people

Tags: mysql

I have this database

```
CREATE TABLE Users(
uid int PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
phone text
);

CREATE TABLE Messages(
recipient int REFERENCES Users(uid),
sender int REFERENCES Users(uid),
time timestamp NOT NULL,
message text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (recipient, sender, time)
);
```

I want to find if there is a message that has been sent more than one times between users.

for example if between 1 have sent the message "Hello" to 5 and also 4 have sent it to 8 for example, I want to print the message "Hello". But if it is only sent one time then I don't want it. I want at least two times to be repeated but at different couples of users. I don't want it to appear if the users 1 and 5 have sent it 2 times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try the following query:

```
SELECT message
FROM Messages
GROUP BY message
HAVING
    MIN(LEAST(sender, recipient)) <> MAX(LEAST(sender, recipient)) OR
    MIN(GREATEST(sender, recipient)) <> MAX(GREATEST(sender, recipient));
```

This logic flags any message which appears more than once and involves two or more different senders or two or more different recipients.

Comment: I don't think that will work for the case where 1 sends to 5 and 5 sends to 1. It's not 100% clear but I don't think those messages are supposed to show either.

Comment: @Nick I fixed it.  Really hard to get it right the first time, as the OP provided no sample data (nor did I take the time to setup a demo).

Comment: guys i've tried this SELECT COUNT(Messages.message), Messages.message
FROM Messages
GROUP BY Messages.message
HAVING COUNT(Messages.message) > 1 But it doesnt work for the case where use 1 sends to 5 the message Hi twice. i want it to be once but from different users.

Comment: Buon giorno Giorgo, please include your attempted query in the _question_, not here.  Comments here should be about my answer.