# Display validation message with duplicate StudentId one by one

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check duplicate Id validation in sql server, that validation grid display
row number , validation message & duplicate ID from sql server

I am not able to understand that how can I do it ?

Help is really appreciate

Create Table

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tbl_Student
    (RowID INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment, StudentID BIGINT);
```

Insert Records

```
Insert into Tbl_Student(RowID,StudentID) values (1,101)
Insert into Tbl_Student(RowID,StudentID) values (2,102)
Insert into Tbl_Student(RowID,StudentID) values (3,101)
Insert into Tbl_Student(RowID,StudentID) values (4,102)
Insert into Tbl_Student(RowID,StudentID) values (5,103)
```

[image]

Please let share if any solution over there

Thank you

Comment: It is mysql syntex

Comment: @GordonLinoff if any solution available you can share sql server code syntax

Comment: No prevention not applicable here, I have to display validation message only for studentId

Comment: in your sample 101 is not duplicated .. expalin better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Query,

```
SELECT RowID, CONCAT('StudentID ',StudentID, ' is Duplicate) AS Error FROM Tbl_Student WHERE StudentID IN (SELECT StudentID FROM Tbl_Student GROUP BY StudentID  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is T-SQL code, you might need to transform it to MySql format:

```
Select * from(
      Select RowId, Count(*) Over(Partition By StudentId Order By RowId) as Cnt From [YourTable]
) as K
Where Cnt>1
```

You can also use `Row_Number` or `Count` aggregate function to achieve the same result too.

Here is plenty of MySql solutions for this problem:

[Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

To display the duplicates I would do:

```
select
  RowID, 
  concat('Student ', StudentID, ' is duplicate') as StudentID
from Tbl_Student where StudentID in (
  select StudentID from Tbl_Student group by StudentID having count(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join on the suquery having count of strundet id > 1

```
  select id,  student_id, concat('Stundent id' , student_id, ' is duplicated')
  from  my_table m
  inner join  (
    select student_id 
    from my_table  
    group by student_id 
    having count(*) > 1  
  ) t on t.student_id  = m.student_id
```