# How to count Most consecutive Duplicate data in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have some data. I want to count most consecutive duplicate data in MySQL. Please help me.

[image]

```
      id        |    data
----------+----------------
2104            |     B
2938            |     B
3545            |     B
4240            |     B
9879            |     A
9995            |     A
9996            |     B
10107           |     B
10563           |     B
11441           |     B
20974           |     A
20975           |     A
23065           |     A
23066           |     A
47469           |     A
47470           |     A
47471           |     A
62091           |     A
62092           |     A      
----------------+-----------------------
```

I look only A.
this answer is 9

```
|    data          |   count
+-------------------------------
|    A             |    9               
+------------------------------
```

Comment: But there are 11 'A's in your input table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Comment: yes. but i count most data Arrange

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Start by getting a count of the various items

```
 SELECT A, COUNT(*) `count`
   FROM tbl
  GROUP BY A
```

Then sort by count and take the first row.

```
 SELECT A, COUNT(*) `count`
   FROM tbl
  GROUP BY A
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

That is easy enough to make me guess there is more to your requirement, however. Please edit your question.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya (smacks forehead) You are right, thanks for the correction. Fixed.