# Duplicate entry key phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to assign the primary key to a column called emailadress in phpmyadmin, and i've been getting the following error:

> #1062 duplicate entry for key "PRIMARY"

This is the SQL-query it tried to run:

```
ALTER TABLE `dparts`  ADD `emailadress` TEXT NOT NULL  AFTER `surname`,  ADD   PRIMARY KEY  (`emailadres`(30)) KEY_BLOCK_SIZE = 30 USING BTREE;
```

I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm not using INT. But then again, why am I not allowed to use text instead of int? Can I get a primary key without having to use INT? If so, how?

Comment: Nothing to do with data type. Primary keys are unique as error says

Comment: Do you have any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Dedupe before altering

Comment: ...and how does one do that?

Comment: Fidn all duplicate and remove them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql