# Show all rows with duplicate from single column

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have the following table :

```
id     user_id     name     age     address
1       12         John      21      earth
2       13         Daniel    19      planet
3       12         Paul      25      here
4       11         Joana     23      mars
5       11         Paul      18      earth
```

The results that I want :

```
id     user_id     name     age     address
1       12         John      21      earth
3       12         Paul      25      here
4       11         Joana     23      mars
5       11         Paul      18      earth
```

So basically, I want to show all rows from duplicated values in the user_id column. I am new to SQL and hopefully, you guys can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
select * from your_table where user_id in (
    select user_id from your_table 
    group by user_id having count(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `exists` for this purpose:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.id <> t.id)
order by user_id, id;
```

In general, it is best to avoid aggregation functions in subqueries if you can -- for performance reasons.