# Find duplicate records with a specific value in column

Tags: mysql

Similar to this [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/854128/6728875), I want to pull out duplicate records in a MySQL database based on the value of a specific column.

To pull out the one with the highest ID, I can do:

```
SELECT MAX(id), name, address, no_purchase, count(id) as cnt FROM list
GROUP BY name, address HAVING cnt > 1
```

To pull out the one with the lowest ID, I can do:

```
SELECT MIN(id), name, address, no_purchase, count(id) as cnt FROM list
GROUP BY name, address HAVING cnt > 1
```

How can I pull it based on the highest no_purchase? When I do MAX(no_purchase), I didn't get the correct id.

Comment: *To pull out the one with the ... ID, I can do* - `no_purchase` value in this case is indefinite.

Comment: do you want to select duplicate records with highest no_purchase ?

Comment: @Akina indefinite but in this case it's fine to pick any row when there are multiple max values.

Comment: @AliFidanli yes, max(no_purchase)

Comment: *but in this case it's fine to pick any row* I believe. But this is a bomb. If the server SQL mode should be changed by any reason your query should fail - do you need in such surprise? Wrap this output column into any aggregate function and make your query synthactically correct.

Comment: @Akina I don't like a bomb. How can I wrap the output column into an aggregate function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One generic solution is this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (name, address, no_purchase) IN (
    SELECT name, address, MAX(no_purchase)
    FROM t
    GROUP BY name, address
)
```

Having said that, using name and address to identify duplicate people does not always work.

Comment: Agree. I have a more complicated database, just to make it simple ^^;

Comment: This solution will get duplicated rows when there are duplicate rows with the same name, address, MAX(no_purchase). Need to add "GROUP BY name, address" after the last ")".