# SQL: Filter rows who have same foreign IDs

Tags: sql

I have the following table, and I want to only get the rows which have the same foreign keys.

```
    id  foreign_id
1   100  a
2   200  a
3   300  b
4   400  c
5   500  c
6   600  d
```

to this:

```
    id  foreign_id
1   100  a
2   200  a
4   400  c
5   500  c
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find duplicate records in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854128/find-duplicate-records-in-mysql)

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Seems like you want to find duplicate attribute values

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to count the number of id's per foreign_id and then only return the rows with a foreign_id having 2 or more (>1) id's.

```
Select
 t.id,
 t.foreign_id
From tablename t
Join
( Select foreign_id fid,
  Count(id) c
  From tablename
  Group by foreign_id ) f
On t.foreign_id = f.fid
Where c > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID, foreign_id
from tablename
WHERE foreign_id in (SELECT foreign_id
                     FROM tablename
                     group by foreign_id
                     having count(foreign_id) > 1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).